# Adding xml namespaces to code programatically

Tags: c#, xml, string, xml-namespaces

I am working on some code in C# where I want the output as the text present at some xpath from some xml-file. Now as the xml file keeps changing and so do the namespaces, I don't want to hardcode the namespaces in the code.

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(file);
XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
```

Now as the namespace keeps changing I am thinking of reading the xml and using some string operations to get the namspace and uri string:

```
string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file);
string[] s1 = new string[1];
s1[0]="xmlns:";
string[] s3 =  s.Split(s1, System.StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (string k in s3)
{
    nsMgr.AddNamespace( k.Substring( 0 , k.IndexOf('=') - 1) , need help for this )
}
```

Some sample values of `k` after the split operation are:

> "xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" "
>
> "location=\"urn:x-ABC:content:location:mastering:1\" "
>
> "entity=\"urn:x-ABC:content:identified-entities:mastering:1\" "

I need help on second parameter of nsMgr.AddNamespace(). Also if there is a cleaner way of adding namespaces without hardcoding.

EDIT:- Clarifying what i am doing here. I am trying to write a winform through which onc can get output as text present at some xpath in some xml.  So winform takes 2 inputs .One is xml file location and other is xpath . The output should be the text at that xpath location.

For example 
    `<a>
     <b>abc
     </b>
     </a>`

if user searches for //b or a/b then output should be abc.

The code works fine when there are default namespaces , but when the xml has namespaces defined i need to include them in the code. As i want to make the code generic , so i cannot hardcode the namespaces.

Comment: The thing is, the namespaces are the "contract" between the producer of the XML and any consumers. They're how you're meant to know that `<abc>` means X and not Y. If the namespaces are changing, you need to find out why.

Comment: By "changing namespaces" i meant that i want my code to be generic ,so that i can use it over any XML file.

Comment: If you're trying to write a library function that is currently being passed `(string xmlFilePath, string xPathQuery)` then you need to also accept a set of namespaces from your caller, if that's what you're trying to do. Any particular xpath query is only well defined if you know the namespaces involved. If that's not what you're trying to do, then it's still unclear.

Comment: i have edited my question to clarify my code.

Comment: An xpath expression of `//b` is *precisely* defined to match `b` elements in the unnamed namespace. An xpath expression of `//a:b` is precisely defined to match `b` elements in the namespace identified by the `a` prefix. To know what the `a` prefix means, we need to know what's in the namespace manager. If the namespace manager contains an entry for the `a` prefix that says that that namespace is `urn:def` then `//a:b` will match the `b` element in `<a><x:b xmlns:x="urn:def"/></a>`. Namespaces are *important* and define meaning, and are independent from prefixes.